# Настройка NAT на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, администрирование, nat

У меня есть Raspbery PI(Ubuntu Mate). К Ethernet интерфейсу подключена IP-камера. Также Raspberry подключен к домашней сети по Wi-Fi. Из домашней сети нужно получить доступ к камере. 
Камера имеет адрес 192.168.1.11, а домашняя подсеть - 192.168.0.x. Следовательно необходимо перенаправить запрос вида 192.168.0.11 на 192.168.1.11. Возможно ли это?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да не обязательно наверно nat настраивать, полагаю, достаточно будет воспользоваться статической маршрутизацией. Если сеть камер не пересекается с сетью роутера, то это идеальное стечение обстоятельств. Raspberry уже знает о сети камеры, осталось рассказать о ней роутеру. Для этого можно использовать динамическую маршрутизацию (например, с помощью демона `quagga` если речь о linux и `ospf` на роутере, если это там возможно), либо статическую маршрутизацию. В последнем случае, нужно просто прописать маршрут на роутере с сетью 192.168.1.0/24 (маска может у Вас отличаться) на адрес 192.168.0.78 (необходимо так же учесть, что raspberry должен всегда получать такой адрес, для этого можно создать статическую dhcp-запись), и на raspberry с сетью 192.168.0.0/24 (маска может у Вас отличаться) в сторону 192.168.0.1 (или какой у Вас там адрес роутера?). Так же возможно понадобится включить **[forwarding](http://gentoo.theserverside.ru/book/ar68s16.html)** на raspberry. Ну, в теории, это делается как-то так :)

Comment: Сделал таким образом. На роутере марштур: `192.168.1.0  mask 255.255.255.0  gate 192.168.0.78(raspberry)`   на raspberry `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1` но камера не пингуется. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте на raspberry с помощью `tcpdump` посмотреть, доходит ли icmp до него. И то ли у Вас опечатка, то ли Вы на raspberry неправильный маршрут указали, там должно быть `route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1` , но скорее всего Вам это и не надо, так как у Вас это скорее всего шлюз по умолчанию, а значит, и без этого маршрута все пакеты должны уходить в роутер.

Comment: что что получаю `11:26:21.627760 IP VirtualBox > 192.168.1.11: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 78, length 40
`

Comment: Действительно была опечатка в маршруте на raspberry, сделал так как вы выше указали. Теперь при пинге камеры получаю "Превышен срок жизни TTL"

Comment: судя по трассировка пакет циклится между роутером и малиной

Comment: уберите маршрут который добавляли на raspberry и убедитесь, что там есть default gateway. Так же убедитесь, что камера знает либо о сети 192.168.0.0/24, либо там указан default gateway. Включите форвардинг на raspberry: `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: действительно, теперь пинг проходит. Но я не могу понять почему не открывается веб-панель камеры. Камера то пингуется

Comment: Смотреть `tcpdump` на raspberry (доходят ли запросы, приходят ли ответы) и проверить настройки камеры, может там какие-то access lists есть.

Comment: слушаю 80 порт, приходят такие запросы `14:31:30.027241 IP 192.168.1.11.http > VirtualBox.12540: Flags [S.], seq 621079699, ack 4212693721, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 5], length 0
E..4..@.?..m.........P0.%.........9.................
`  Ответов нет я так понимаю.

Comment: Так это ответ, а не запрос, раз он с `192.168.1.11` (адрес камеры) на  некий `VirtualBox` (полагаю это что-то из сети 192.168.0.0/24 должно быть). Значит надо на device дампить трафик. Возможно по какой-то причине роутер не пропускает www-трафик .

Comment: На другом роутере без проблем и веб-панель заработала. Меня это устраивает. Спасибо за помощь.